How to model buttons for a calculator
I'm not sure whether to model the buttons all from one object, or to create one and then duplicate it?  Would it be better to make them solid meshes, or from a plane mesh?


Hello, yes, create one and repeat

I don't see any particular reason one way would be better then the other. Usually it's better to make one and duplicate, however these can probably be modeled simultaneously extruding individual faces and then performing operations on all of them at the same time this way avoiding the need to move and connect separate geometry later and it might make dealing with corners of the keypad easier.
